# efficient conversion of 2D to 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data array containing ndim coordinates of N particles over timesteps 1 to M. The columns in the array typically represent the (x,y,z) of each particle 'p', and each row in the array represents another time point 't':

```
x_t1p1  y_t1p1  z_t1p1  x_t1p2  y_t1p2  z_t1p2  ...  x_t1pN  y_t1pN  z_t1pN
x_t2p1  y_t2p1  z_t2p1  x_t2p2  y_t2p2  z_t2p2  ...  x_t2pN  y_t2pN  z_t2pN
...
x_tMp1  y_tMp1  z_tMp1  x_tMp2  y_tMp2  z_t1p2  ...  x_tMpN  y_tMpN  z_tMpN
```

I would like to convert the array to a 3D format such that each particle is in a different (M x ndim) 'slice' of the numpy array. I am currently doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
def datarray_to_3D(data, ndim=3):
    (nr,nc) = data.shape
    nparticles = nc/ndim
    dat_3D = np.zeros([nr,ndim,nparticles])
    for i in range(nparticles):
        dat_3D[:,:,i] = data[:,i*ndim:(i+1)*ndim]
    return dat_3D
```

I have a basic knowledge of NumPy, but would like to increase my proficiency in array manipulation. How can the above function be rewritten to eliminate the loop and use a more 'NumPythonic' structure?

Thank you.

-c

Answer (score 2):

Original solution, slightly different than your function.

```
def datarray_to_3D(data, nparticles=3):
    nr, nc = data.shape
    data = data.reshape(nr, nparticles, nc/nparticles)
    return np.rollaxis(data, 2, 1)
```

Update: I've updated my original answer to make my mistake more clear, Thanks unutbu for catching it. My solution took `nparticles` as an argument instead of `ndim` where `nparticles * ndim == data.shape[1]`. I made the mistake partly becuase I changed the name of your variable `ndim`. I would avoid using `ndim` as a variable name in this case because it is too similar to the attribute `data.ndim` which is the number of dimensions of the array. Here is the updated solution, but I've replaced `ndim by`dim1`. It is more similar to your original function.

```
def datarray_to_3D(data, dim1=3):
    nr, nc = data.shape
    data = data.reshape(nr, nc/dim1, dim1)
    return np.rollaxis(data, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I was looking for and allows me the chance to explore the reshape and rollaxis methods.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def alt_3D(data, ndim=3):
    nr, nc = data.shape
    result = data.reshape(nr,-1,3).transpose(0,2,1)
    return result
```

For example, if

```
data = np.arange(18).reshape((-1,6))
```

then `alt_3D(data)` yields:

```
[[[ 0  3]
  [ 1  4]
  [ 2  5]]

 [[ 6  9]
  [ 7 10]
  [ 8 11]]

 [[12 15]
  [13 16]
  [14 17]]]
```

(This is a different result than Bago's answer.)